# This article in a major Australian newspaper says Aussies just gained visa-free access to Japan. Didn't we already have it?

Tags: japan, australia, us-visa-waiver-program, visa-free-entry, australian-citizens

I've been visiting Japan for something like twenty years with Australian passports and never needed to obtain a visa in advance. I've always been granted 90-day stays. I was there a few months before the pandemic and a few months after it.

But just now I was reading [a July 20, 2023 article in the Sydney Morning Herald](https://www.smh.com.au/traveller/travel-news/australian-passports-just-became-more-powerful-here-are-the-countries-you-can-now-enter-visa-free-20230719-p5dpde.html) about how Singapore's passport is now the best in the world and also which countries Australia has lost and gained visa-free access to.

Here's the two places they mention Australia-Japan:

> The Australian passport’s ascension is due to increasing its visa-free access to 186 destinations around the world, up from 185 earlier this year, after **losing visa-free access** to **Ethiopia**, **Papua New Guinea** and **Uganda**, and gaining access to ***Japan***, **Mongolia**, **Suriname** and **Djibouti**. It’s Australia’s highest ranking since 2015, and it shares the sixth position with Hungary and Poland.

> Newest visa-free destinations for Australians
>
> 1. **Japan**
> 2. Mongolia
> 3. Suriname
> 4. Djibouti

So is this just a typical ignorant journalism howler, or is there some technical change like maybe we were on a visa-waiver regime before and now we're on a visa-free regime?

I'm Googling for more details but our experts here are more cluey than the Google (-:

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> So is this just a typical ignorant journalism howler

Yes and no

What they're referring to is the release of the **annual** 2023 [Henley Passport Index](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henley_Passport_Index)

The fact that it is annual means that the previous 2022 index takes into account the fact that Australia (like all countries) lost visa-free access there during the pandemic.

It was restored on [Oct, 11th, 2022](https://asia.nikkei.com/Spotlight/Coronavirus/Japan-set-to-announce-restart-of-visa-free-tourist-travel), and so counts as a difference between this year's index with visa-free travel and last year's index (Published on January, 15th 2022) without visa-free entry.

---

For anyone that doesn't know, the report **does** state that Australia and all gained visa-free entry to Japan, which is factually true, but it's a restoration of the right, so I'd assume it's a copy paste thing.

Comment: Ah I actually thought of that possibility but considered it too silly to be the likely reason behind the news.

Comment: Basically, then, every newspaper in the world is running a story like this about "new" visa free access to Japan?

Comment: Talking about "earlier this year" while referencing a document that is only updated once a year seems like a howler to me.